# how to get the smallest value in javascript by getting data from DOM

Tags: javascript, arrays, dom, numbers, digit

I have a problem with my javascript. 
So this the data :
0   | 29 | 6   | 25
29 | 0    | 25 | 12
6    | 23 | 0   |  19
25 | 12 | 19 | 0

When i get the smallest value except 0 by some javascripts syntaxs, javascript says that the smallest value is 12, not 6.

Javascript chooses '12' because 6 is bigger than 12 "*at the first digit*".

Should to know that i get the data by using DOM (using innerHTML method) from html. 
So is that can affect the value of the variabel, when i get the data (numbers) by using DOM, then the data will be read by javascript for each digit, not the entire digit?

Or is that some syntaxes that i can use, so javascript can read value (numbers) by entire digit not by each digit, when it compares between '15' and '8' or something like that.

Thanks.

Comment: Post your code, please.

Comment: It sounds like you are comparing them as strings rather than comparing them as integers. Also, FWIW, the smallest number is `0`.

Comment: use `Number(element.innerHTML)` or `parseInt(element.innerHTML)`

Comment: Ow, sorry i mean the smallest value except 0. Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are comparing each variable as a `string`. Try using the `parseInt` function to compare the variables numerically.

Answer (score 0):

You are likely comparing the string value rather than the integer value. Pass the value returned by the DOM through [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) to get the proper integer value before comparison.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your values to a number, with the `parseInt(**value**)` method.